# How to exclude '@' in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem related to regular expression that I want to exclude one character but I did not know how.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.*;

class ExtractDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "From foo@gmail.com Fri Jan 5 09:14:16 2016";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@.*?\\s");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);


    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found a " + m.group() + ".");
    }
}
```

}

The output is '@gmail.com' However I want to delete '@'. So the output would be 'gmail.com'

I have tried the expression: ("[^@].*?\s") but it did not work :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: use a lookbehind or use a capture group.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for notifying me :)

Comment: Thanks for the response :). Do you mean something like ("(?<!@).*?\\s"). I tried it but it does not work well.

Comment: You use a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)`, use a positive lookbehind `(?<=...)`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. I was looking for a solution for more than two hours.

Comment: Look at @Saleem 's answer too that does it with a capture group. *(and that avoids the non-greedy quantifier using the `\S` character class.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to write regex as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "From foo@gmail.com Fri Jan 5 09:14:16 2016";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=@)(\\w+(\\.\\w+)+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found a " + m.group(1) + ".");
    }
}
```

I'm checking `@` in non capturing block so final output will capture only `gmail.com` but not `gmail..com`

Comment: You don't need to use a non-capturing group around @.

Comment: well, this is one of many ways to do what needs to be done :)  Yes there are  +- lookbehind to do same too.

Comment: `Pattern.compile("(?<=@)(\\w+(\\.\\w+)+)");` will do same. But as you can see non capturing groups are much simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: You didn't understand, I just suggested to remove the useless non-capturing group `(?:...)`, like this: `@(\\S+)`

Comment: Note that the use of a lookbehind doesn't make the pattern more complicated: `(?<=@)\\S+`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  yes I agree. I usually preferred approach which is more portable around different regex engines. As you can see I have altered final regex little bit. above regex will match `gmail.com, gmail.com.uk` but not `gmail..com`

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to change your initial `\\S+` to something that try to check a domain name format, because it isn't the goal here and because a domain name can be more complicated than words characters separated by dots (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_syntax and the RFCs to make nightmares).

Comment: Totally agreed. DNS is very complicated beast. I was taking little liberty while honoring original request. Again, your solution is absolutely correct and as you can see above, I'v voted for it.